# CMake: print root project name using cmake commandline

Tags: cmake, cmake-cache

Is it possible to print project name value of a CMake project using cmake.exe?

for example:

> cmake -LA CMakeLists.txt | grep CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX

to get the install prefix configured for the project.

Is there any way similar to get CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME which is defined in project('xyz')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable [CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME.html) is not a cached one, so it cannot be printed by running `cmake -LA`.

Using variable [CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE.html) it is possible to define a **hook** for `project()` calls. That hook could just print a project name.

For example, consider such script `project_hook.cmake`:

```
message(STATUS "Project name is ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

You could configure a CMake project with

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE=</path/to/project_hook.cmake> </path/to/source/dir> | grep -m1 "Project name is"
```

so you will get the line

```
Project name is <...>
```

for the first `project()` call encountered in the CMake project.

This approach works for CMake 3.15 or newer.

Comment: You could even create a cache entry from `project_hook.cmake` and then use `cmake -LA` to pull it out of the cache.